# Printer says "ready" but won't print

Tags: printing, canon

I connected my printer (canon ip8700) via usb and I received a notification that it was all set up and ready to go.  I went to the settings page and the printer's status is "ready" but it won't print anything. I tried to print the test page but it doesn't do anything.  No status changes, nothing.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I forgot to include that Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you install drivers?

Comment: Is there a specific way to do that? I clicked the settings clicked "search for drivers".  It never told me if it found any or not?

Comment: Just to check: does the printer print a test page when you use the physical buttons, without using ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah it prints a test page.  I printed the test page from pressing the buttons and I printed a network config page.  I just install Ubuntu, previously I had windows 10 and it worked perfectly. @GyroGearloose

Comment: Is this Canon IP8770 or IP8700? I googled and found a painter driver for the former in one of Canon's web site.

Comment: @user68186 yeah its a 8700 series 8720 to be exact.  I downloaded those drivers, but I'm not sure if they helped or not.  It ended up working but I wasn't 100% sure how or what made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution to this problem but I ran this command:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Works perfectly...for now.